# Lambda erreur Bucket name must match the regex

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am looking to copy a json stored in an S3 bucket and put it in DynamoDB.
Here is the code for my lambda:

```
import boto3
import json
import ast
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb_client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # First we will fetch bucket name from event json object
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    # Now we will fetch file name which is uploaded in s3 bucket from event json object
    json_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    #Lets call get_object() function which Retrieves objects from Amazon S3 as dictonary
    json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=json_file_name)
    # Lets decode the json object returned by function which will retun string
    file_reader = json_object['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
    # We will now change this json string to dictonary
    file_reader = ast.literal_eval(file_reader)
    # As we have retrieved the dictionary we will put it in dynamodb table
    table = dynamodb_client.Table('Annonceur')
    table.put_item(Item=file_reader)
    return 'success'
```

And here is the code for the JSON event

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "eu-west-3",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789",
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "s3://cleandataemr/data_EMR/df_annonceur5.json/",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::cleandataemr/data_EMR/df_annonceur5.json/part-00000-19cabb09-baed-4015-9b3a-0d9422720b82-c000.json"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "part-00000-19cabb09-baed-4015-9b3a-0d9422720b82-c000.json",
          "size": 1024,
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I get this error when I test my code

Test Event Name
eventtest

This is the response I get

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid bucket name \"s3://cleandataemr/data_EMR/df_annonceur5.json/\": Bucket name must match the regex \"^[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-_]{1,255}$\" or be an ARN matching the regex \"^arn:(aws).*:(s3|s3-object-lambda):[a-z\\-0-9]*:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\\-.]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z\\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{1,63}$\"",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError"
}
```

If I look in the function logs, this is what I see

```
START RequestId: 10411c35-891d-428e-827b-9f79a4482073 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "s3://cleandataemr/data_EMR/df_annonceur5.json/": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:(s3|s3-object-lambda):[a-z\-0-9]*:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-.]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$"
```

Thanks for your help

Inès

Comment: I don't fully understand that you appear to have a bucket name with a `/` character in it.  That should be part of the key, not the bucket name.  Is the JSON above a real event?

Comment: Your test data has a full S3 object URL for the bucket name. Where did you get this test data? The bucket name is `cleandataemr`.